# Scala wait of list of future to execute

Tags: scala, akka, scala-collections, akka-stream

Hi I am trying to process data in a file.

This the code I am using below.

I have a list of Futures and trying to get the output from these futures.

Everything is fine but the last line of return is executing before OnSuccess.

How can I change that behaviour without having a blocking operation.

```
def processRow(rowNumber: Int, row: String, delimiter: String, rules: List[Rule]): RowMessage = {
var cells = row.split(delimiter)
var passedRules = new ListBuffer[RuleResult]()
val failedRules = new ListBuffer[RuleResult]()
val rulesFuture = rules.map {
  i => Future {
    val cells = row.split(delimiter);
    //some processing....
  }
}
val f1 = Future.sequence(rulesFuture)
f1 onComplete {
  case Success(results) => for (result <- results) (result.map(x => {
    if (x.isPassFailed) {
      passedRules += x
    }
    else {
      failedRules += x
    }
  }))
  case Failure(t) => println("An error has occured: " + t.getMessage)
}
return new RowMessage(passedRules.toList,   failedRules.toList)
}
```

Comment: what does it have to do with akka streams?

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid blocking and return a plain `RowMessage`. You need to return a `Future`as well.

```
def processRow(rowNumber: Int, row: String, delimiter: String, rules: List[Rule]): Future[RowMessage] = {
  val cells = row.split(delimiter)
  Future.traverse(rules) { i =>
    Future {
      //some processing....
    }
  } map { results =>
    val (passed, failed) = results.partition(_.isPassFailed)
    new RowMessage(passed, failed)
  }
}
```

Also think about your algorithm to avoid mutable state, especially when you change it from different Futures.

`Future.traverse` is equivalent of your `map` + `Future.sequence`. Then instead of onComplete, just map your `Future` to modify the list. You can split it easly using `partition` instead of what you've been doing.

You don't need to use `return`, in fact you shouldn't unless you know what you are doing.

Btw `isPassFailed` doesn't sound like a reasonable method name to me, especially considering that when it's true you are adding it to passed rules.